# String is blank when sending with Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send a String from one activity to another using intents, however whenver I send it over and set a TextView to that string, the string is blank. Here is the Intent code:

```
String homeTeam = "temp";
String awayTeam = "temp";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gaelic_param);

    EditText homeTeamEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.HomeTeam);
    EditText awayTeamEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AwayTeam);

    homeTeam = homeTeamEditText.getText().toString();
    awayTeam = awayTeamEditText.getText().toString();
}

public void nextPage(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(GaelicParam.this, GaelicActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("homeTeamExtra", homeTeam);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Here is what I do to set the text.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gaelic_main);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null) {
        String HomeTeam = extras.getString("homeTeamExtra");

        TextView homeTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.homeTeam_text_view);
        homeTextView.setText(HomeTeam);
    }
}
```

However the textView is still empty.

Comment: you're not calling `nextPage` anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code 
put `homeTeam = homeTeamEditText.getText().toString();` inside so it will take latest value of editText

```
public void nextPage(View view){
homeTeam = homeTeamEditText.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(GaelicParam.this, GaelicActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("homeTeamExtra", homeTeam);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, bit of an idiot wasn't thinking! Much appreciated

Comment: if it solves your problem then please select the answer! glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Use method **getStringExtra** to retrieve from putExtra (string value)

```
intent.getStringExtra("homeTeamExtra");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `homeTeam` is only being set in the sending activity when it is created, so it will not reflect any changes to the EditText. The easiest way to solve this would be to retrieve the text in the EditText when the next page is requested, for example:

```
public void nextPage(View view) {
    EditText homeTeamEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.HomeTeam);
    Intent intent = new Intent(GaelicParam.this, GaelicActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("homeTeamExtra", homeTeamEditText.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

If you want `homeTeam` to always reflect the current text in the EditText, you can try using a [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, bit of an idiot wasn't thinking! Much appreciated